# перекрытия виджета

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты

На виджете есть `QLabel`. Как сделать так, чтобы при щелчке по `QLabel` срабатывал слот `mouseReleaseEvent` виджета, а не `QLabel`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого используется `QEventFilter`:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label->installEventFilter(this);  //устанавливаем фильтр
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease &&
            target == ui->label)  //проверяем тип события и отправителя
    {
        mouseReleaseEvent((QMouseEvent *)event);   //приводим событие к нужному типу 
        //и отправляем в окно 
        return true;
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(target, event);
}

void MainWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug()<<"release!";
}
```